# How do "collisions" occur on Firebase data updates?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

In my application, I'm storing the data of my users in Firebase's real-time database. It can happen that I modify one of its data via `setValue` and that there is directly afterwards another modification of this same data (for example on the user spamming this action button), and thus I think that there can be two writings in the same place at the same time.
Already I wanted to know if what I said true or if anyway with the time lag between the two clicks, the changes can't occur simultaneously.
For the moment I have managed this problem by hiding the button until the modification finished, but it turns out that the problem is already managed by Firebase and I don't know it.

If anyone can help me out, that would be great :)

Comment: You need to take a look at [Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) which state **When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation**

Comment: If we knew a bit more about the use case, we may be able to provide a more complete answer; are you trying to avoid concurrent writes *there can be two writings in the same place at the same time* or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

In the Firebase realtime database the last change will be saved. If you don't want to overried other fields on a path use `update` instead of `set`. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

Comment: @MarwanTragha This answer while accurate, doesn't really have anything to do with preventing collisions - that's handled via Firebase Transactions (see my comment to your question). This answer is simply stating how to not override data at a specific path, whereas you want to be able to overwrite data at a path but just not concurrently. It's still good info, just doesn't directly apply. Also, that link is for Web, not iOS and also note you can use `.set` to update a specific field while not overwriting other fields - `.update` is for updating multiple nodes aka "fan-out" update

Comment: @Jay thx for the extra input. I have updated the link to the `ios` docu. As far as I can tell he just needed a clarification if Firebase is managing concurrent writes or not.  Sometimes simple questions are enought. From the question I don't see any reason he would need to use a transaction. Maybe if he would tell us what kind of data he tries to write we can tell more about it.

Comment: Agreed. This is the thing that caught my attention *there can be two writings in the same place at the same time.* but maybe they will clarify.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reactions, indeed it was just in the case of simultaneous writing. In fact if the user presses a button twice in a row then it writes twice to the same place in the database.